# How do you determine the size of an index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have an index -- let's call it `IX_MY_INDEX` -- in a SQL Server table (both compatibility modes 80 and 90) that I would like to determine the size of. How do I do this?

**Update:** Allain Lalonde's second solution below only works when the compatibility mode is set to 90; however, the particular database I am working on is in compatibility mode 80. Does anyone have a solution for compatibility mode 80?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can determine the size of all indexes on a table (and other things) like so:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused TableName;
```

For a full breakdown you may:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('TableName'), null, null, 'DETAILED');
```

Comment: Many thanks. The second option you have given returns this error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: It seems that the query is failing because I'm in 80 compatibility mode. Do you have a solution for 90 compatibility?

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from the post on [How to Find Size of All the Indexes on the Database](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/11/13/find-size-indexes-database-interview-question-week-097/), you can use:

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) AS SchemaName,
       OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
       i.[name] AS IndexName,
       i.index_id AS IndexID,
       8 * SUM(a.used_pages) AS [Indexsize(KB)]
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.partitions p ON p.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID AND p.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
GROUP BY i.OBJECT_ID, i.index_id, i.[name]
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID), i.index_id
```

Which uses the following tables:

- [`sys.indexes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql)
- [`sys.partitions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql)
- [`sys.allocation_units`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql)